# Read array of numbers in C

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I am practicing algorithms problems online, and encountered an input problem:

I know how to read

```
1 2 3 -4 5
```

using

```c
int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
while(scanf("%d", p++) != EOF) {
    //
}
```

But the problem's input is defined as

```
[1, 2, 3, -4, 5]
```

how to read this format input into integer array?

Comment: Read input until `scanf("%d", ..."` fails to return 1 and the next input is a `']'`?  Can a line of input have 0 numbers?  What is the upper count of numbers? What is the range of allowable integers? What if input is non-numeric?  Knowing this helps to make a better solution.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, it's just a simple demo to demonstrate the problem, not a real application, no need to add complexity to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can get you started,

```
int main () {
    int size = 5;
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    char buf[200] = {0};

    fgets(buf, 200, stdin);

    char *token = strtok(buf, "[, ");
    while(token) {
        *p = atoi(token);
        printf("next is %d,\n", *p);
        token = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        ++p;
    }
}
```

Note this assumes that you only have an input of 5 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to read it as characters and convert it later into numbers using atoi().

```c
char buffer[10],tmp;
```

This will be the buffer for the number as ASCII

```c
while(tmp!=']')
    {
        tmp=getchar();
        if(tmp>=0x30 && tmp<0x3A)
            buff[i++]=tmp;
        else if(tmp!='[')
        {
            buff[i]='\0';
            arr[j++]=atoi(buff);    //numbers stored to arr array
            i=0;
        }
    }
```

This code will read each character form screen and identify numbers and add it to the buffer. Then when another character is encountered, we know the number is finished and it is converted and stored into the array.